# IntelliJ IDEA lost icon after launch

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I changed to use JetBrains Toolbox App to manage IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm/WebStorm (I have reinstalled all the JetBrains products using Toolbox App) in my Ubuntu 16.04.2 recent days. Now I have an issue: each time when I started IntelliJ IDEA from the Toolbox App or from the command line (`./idea.sh`), IntelliJ IDEA could run as I wished but without an icon in the launcher bar, only a white question mark. However, if I start it by double-click the thumbnail of it, everything would be OK, including a beautiful icon in my ubuntu launcher bar!

Does anyone know how to fix? This is not a big trouble, but I just want to make everything fine with my develop environment.

Comment: I had similar problems on my fresh install but everything go fine on reboot. Which Desktop GUI are you using ?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149703.

Comment: unity@HollyPony

Comment: @nick Have you tried to see if it's a relic of old installs ? You can edit your apps entries easily with [alacarte](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alacarte) and start the app "Menu". Then delete entries for JetBrains apps and reinstall. The icon menu is maybe still linked to the old path (and yes, as I know, it's impact whole system icon integration).

Comment: I will check right now!@HollyPony

Answer (score 10):

I do not know if it would work for `Gnome`, but for `KDE` I fixed it in the next way:

1. Open folder `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/`
2. Find `jetbrains-idea.desktop`.
3. Right mouse click on it, then select `Properties`
4. Open `Application` tab
5. Next to the `Command` section click `Browse...` button and select `idea.sh` file in `/pathToIntelliJ/bin` folder. (In my case the path was already correct, but it seems that selection the file again rewrite something and Icon works ok now).
6. Click `OK`.

Also, [according to this post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149703#focus=streamItem-27-3054493-0-0), this bug must be fixed in 18.3 (now is 18.2.5)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using KDE, and the icon will show correctly everywhere but the favorites menu.

The issue appears to be that the icon selected is an svg instead of png. The .desktop file that others are instructing to right click on can instead be edited since it's basically a text file.

Open `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop` in an editor.

Look for the line that starts with `Icon=` and change the `.svg` to `.png`.

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 3):

In my case on Ubuntu 18.04 with Plasma 5, I had a similar issue with WebStorm; I had two .desktop files in `~/.local/share/application` and `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/application` directories.
After removing .desktop file from `~/.local/share/application` directory, all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but not the same resolution.  My icon completely disappeared after the last intellij upgrade.  I fixed this by following the same steps as TitanFighter to get to the jetbrains-idea.desktop, but had a different fix, as the icon just disappeared from the desktop file.  This solution was on Kubuntu 18.10.

1. After opening Properties on jetbrains-idea.desktop, click the square next to the name of the file.
2. Select the 'Other icons:' option and click 'Browse...'
3. Navigate to the Intellij/bin folder and double click idea.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing issues on Manjaro with XFCE in the favorites panel after each upgrade via the Toolbox. For me I had to manually reset the icons to their current versions, which at least on Manjaro are .pngs in: `/var/lib/snapd/snap/<pycharm-professional or other ide name>/current/bin`. I'm unsure as to why Snap upgrades inevitably remove the icons on all Jetbrains products in the favorites panel.